Closed Form Solution for Sawtooth Frequency Sweep
To make a sawtooth wave with constant freqency $f_0$, we can use:
$$
f(t) = (t*f_0) \bmod 1
$$
It is also possible to express this using trigonometric functions.
Is there an expression $f(t)$ for a sawtooth wave with frequency $f_0$ at $t=0$, linearly changing frequency to $f_1$ at $t=t_{max}$?
The sawtooth should have constant slope of 1 between the discontinuities, and variable amplitude based on that.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

What you are looking for is a kind of "signal" called a chirp.

What you have added is an Interesting approach. Any comment about my own approach, which, once more, has been downvoted ?

@JeanMarie Your approach is interesting and I upvoted it. It doesn't quite work as a solution to the problem because 1. want a proper sawtooth with discontinuities and 2. the slope is not constant.

(Too long for a comment)
By "fiddling" with functions like :
$$\begin{cases}f_1(x)&=&\arccos(\sin(x))\\
f_2(x)&=&\arcsin(\cos(x))\\f_3(x)&=&\arcsin(\sin(x))\\f_4(x)&=&\arccos(\cos(x))\end{cases},$$

Fig. 1 : $f_1$ in black, $f_2$ in red, $f_3$ in blue, $f_4$ in green ; please note that all of them have a $2\pi$ period periodicity ; $f_2$ and $f_4$ are even functions, and $f_3$ is an odd function.
I have found a (visually) convenient "chirp" by taking :
$$f(x)=\arcsin(\cos(x^2))$$
(Fig. 2) Your opinion ?

Fig. 2.

I have modified my answer.

We can construct a stairstep function with changing frequency like this:
$$
\text{let } b=1.2\\
f_s(t) = b^{\lfloor \log_b(t+1) \rfloor} - 1
$$
Here's a graph (the red line representing f(t)=t)

This function can be trivially converted into a sawtooth by using $f(t) = t-f_s(t)$, resulting in:

In order to change the starting frequency, we can replace the floor function with a "rounding to nearest multiple of k" operation and then derive the proper value of k.
However, I haven't found a way to change the slope of the frequency yet.
